# How to search in a key/value PostgreSQL json field?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, date

I have a field in my PSQL database with this datas:

```json
{
  "1":{
    "wp_post_id":137840,
    "sync_at":{
      "date":"2021-02-23 22:02:35.958325",
      "timezone_type":3,
      "timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"
    }
  },
  "3":{
    "wp_post_id":773,
    "sync_at":{
      "date":"2021-05-25 16:17:14.322988",
      "timezone_type":3,
      "timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"
    }
  }
}
```

I try to search records with `sync_at` lower than another date without success…
Maybe my field format is not good?!

Comment: Do you want to know if any of the entries meets the condition or do you want to extract only those parts of the JSON that match?

Comment: I want to know if at least one entry of the field meets the condition (sync_at < my_date).

Comment: Looks like you are dumping the php datetime object as-is into the json then trying to do date math using pgsql. It would be better if you store something that both platforms could understand e.g. Unix timestamps or the datetime converted to utc

Comment: This would be a lot simpler with a properly normalized data model

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that would be a JSONPATH query (available since v12):

```
WHERE jsoncol @@ '$.*.sync_at.date < "2020-06-01 00:00:00"'
```

The query is simple, but there is no way to make it fast with an index.